# Hard Disk Drive deflecting heat cover - or what?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

Recently I've found this:

[image: thing]

...covering HDD in Lenovo laptop.

I'm wondering - is it some kind of heat shield?

Is it necessary to cover SSD with it, in case of replacing HDD?
As far as I know, SSD's have no overheating issues.

Comment: It looks suspeciously like an anti static bag. And I've never seen one of these in any thinkpad I've taken apart. Is the material stiff or flexible? Was it on top or below the hard drive?

Comment: It is flexible and it was on top of the hard drive, attached with a little amount of adhesive tape.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Are you sure? They're fairly common really, definitely not anti-static bags. It's a thin sheet of metal, I've never really wondered what it was for but certainly seen them around, assumed for heat reasons though. https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MUbYKqw-yrk/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: If I was sure, I'd post an answer :p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Can't argue with that... :)

Comment: @Jonno It's exactly how HDD looked like.

Comment: When you say "on top", are you referring to the side with the board, or the other side (that likely is just the drive shell and maybe label)? Edit your question to include this data, and you may get some more helpful answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you exactly what it's for, I've always assumed for heat (and attracting fingerprints), but it's certainly not essential to the operation of the machine.

To answer your question, you can safely ignore this part when fitting your SSD without any detrimental effect.

A couple of other images of it in use, however I've refitted original hard drives without them and not noticed any negative effects.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hm. That covers the circuit board. Can't be electrically conductive then I guess? Would work as shielding too...